# The joint P.M.F. of Hypergeometric and Negative Binomial Distributions

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, negative-binomial-distribution

A forest contains 100 deer. 20 of them have a red tag and 80 of them are untagged. A researcher samples 30 random deer without replacement. Let X be the number of tagged deer in the sample. From the sample of 30 deer, she will keep picking deer with replacement until she picks the fourth tagged deer. Let Y be the number of selections she makes until she gets her fourth tagged deer. Find the joint pmf of X and Y.

This is my Solution, can someone take a look for me.
Let X be the number of tagged deer in the sample of 30 random deer without replacement.
$$X \sim \text{Hypergeometric(}N=100, n=30, r=20).$$
Let Y be the number of selections from the sample of 30 deer she makes until she gets her fourth tagged deer.
$$Y|X \sim \text{Negative Binomial(}r=4, \frac{X}{30}).$$
The joint P.M.F. of X and Y is as following:
$$P_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}0 &\text{for X=0 and Y is finite} \\ P(X=0)=\dfrac{\dbinom{20}{0}\dbinom{80}{30-0}}{\dbinom{100}{30}} &\text{for X=0 and Y is infinite} \\P_X(x)P_{Y|X}(y|x) = \dfrac{\dbinom{20}{x}\dbinom{80}{30-x}}{\dbinom{100}{30}} \dbinom{y-1}{4-1} (1-\frac{x}{30})^{30-4} (\frac{x}{30})^4   &\text{for }X=1,2,\dots ,20; \text { }Y=4,5,\dots \\  0 &\text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$$ 
Thank you.

Comment: Would you say Y equals infinity if X=0?. Clearly when X=0 she will never draw 4 tagged deer The probability that X=0 is positive and you might say that the joint probability That X=0 and Y equals infinity is the same as the marginal probability that X=0 and is not 0. It seems that this one possibility is not included in your derived joint distribution..

Comment: Clearly, when x=0 then there is no tagged deer in the sample to pick, you are absolutely right. The Y equals to infinity but the problem here I can't find the relationship between X and Y when X=1,2,....

Comment: Your correction is not quite right.  For X=0 and Y finite the joint probability is 0 and when X=0 and Y is infinite the joint probability is simply the probability that X=0.

Comment: No the way I see it when X=0 Y is guaranteed to be infinity.  So its probability is just the same as the probability that X=0. I think the way you have it now is correct.

Comment: Can you explain why we need to have 2 cases where (X=0 and Y is infinite) and (X=0 and Y is finite) and why in the case (X=0 and Y is infinite) the joint p.m.f. is the probability of X=0.  I think when X=0, regardless of value Y, the joint p.m.f. is always 0.Thanks. @Michael Chernick.

Comment: I think if you do what you say when you sum up the joint probabilities without the point at infinity the probabilities will not sum to 1. It will be missing the P(X=0). As you have shwn that probability is greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

The Negative Binomial part in the answer is not correct, it should be$$\mathbb{P}(Y=y|X=x)=\binom{y-1}{4-1}\left(\frac{x}{30}\right)^4\left(1-\frac{x}{30}\right)^{y-4}\qquad x\ge 1,y\ge 4$$

Comment: Thanks you for correcting me. I still don't understand why $P_{X,Y}(x,y)=P(X=0)=\dfrac{\dbinom{20}{0}\dbinom{80}{30-0}}{\dbinom{100}{30}} \text{for X=0 and Y is infinite}$. Could you explain this case?

Comment: This is the Hypergeometric probability for $X=0$, where is the difficulty?

Comment: I understand the Hypergeometry distribution and why Y follows Hypergeometry distribution.  I do not understand is why we have two cases where X=0, Y is finite and X=0, Y is infinite and when X=0, Y is infinite, the joint probability of X and Y equals the probability of X.

Comment: The first case has probability zero, not a case of interest. The second case tells you that $Y$ is infinite with probability one when $X=0$.

Comment: If I understand correctly then in the second case when X=0 and Y is infinite $\mathbb{P}(Y=y|X=x)=\sum_{y=4}^{\infty}\binom{y-1}{4-1}\left(\frac{x}{30}\right)^4\left(1-\frac{x}{30}\right)^{y-4}=1$ hence $P_{X,Y}(x,y)=P_X(x)$.